# how to hide/show the panels with drop down list change in asp with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have one dropdownlist and 5 panel 
I want when the drop down list is changed only one panel show
for panels add css code(display:none;)
now if dropdownlist is changed :value of drop down list compare with one value then one panel show and others panel hide.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DropDownList1_collection').change(function () {
        if ($("#DropDownList1_collection").val() === "abcdef")
            $('#Panel1_LavazemElectroniki').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the same conditions for any other conditions to match with.

```
$('#DropDownList1_collection').change(function () {
    if ($("#DropDownList1_collection").val() === "abcdef"){
        $('#Panel1_LavazemElectroniki').show();
        $('#Panel2_LavazemElectroniki').hide();
        $('#Panel3_LavazemElectroniki').hide();
        $('#Panel4_LavazemElectroniki').hide();
        $('#Panel5_LavazemElectroniki').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
$('div[class^="drop-"]').hide();

$('select').change(function() {
  a = $(this).val();
  $('div[class^="drop-"]').hide();
  $('.drop-' + a).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<div class="drop-1">dropdown 1</div>
<div class="drop-2">dropdown 2</div>
<div class="drop-3">dropdown 3</div>
```